# How to set a subdomain as 'sub.domain.appspot.com' on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, subdomain

I know how to set up an app on google app engine as myapp.appspot.com, but I hope to use a.myapp.appspot.com and b.myall.appspot.com for different interfaces of the same app. As google instruction said, this is supported:

> appspot.com domains also support subdomains of the form subdomain.your_app_id.appspot.com, where subdomain can be any string allowed in one part of a domain name (not .). Requests sent to any subdomain in this way are routed to your application.
>
> <sub>From https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime</sub>

But I cannot figure it out how to set up. Has anyone ever created subdomain on appspot?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do anything to set that up. It just works.

That said, to implement different interfaces, you need to detect the hostname the caller used. You can get this in `HTTP_HOST`. `HTTP_HOST` will have the full name (i.e. "a.myapp.appspot.com" or "b.myapp.appspot.com").

UPDATE: the answer no longer applies if using HTTPS, from [Routing via URL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#routing_via_url):

> **Note:** Google [recommends](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal_6.html) using the HTTPS protocol to send requests to your app. Google does not issue SSL certificates for
>   double-wildcard domains hosted at appspot.com. Therefore with HTTPS
>   you must use the string "-dot-" instead of "." to separate subdomains,
>   as shown in the examples below. You can use a simple "." with your own
>   custom domain or with HTTP addresses.

Comment: keep in mind that here `a` and `b` could be 2 different versions of the app. so appengine serves a different version if the version name matches, otherwise it will serve the default version.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `SERVICE_ID-dot-` notion:

```
https://SERVICE_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com
```

```
https://myall.appspot.com/

https://a-dot-myall.appspot.com/
https://b-dot-myall.appspot.com/
```

Here, requests with a-dot-myall.appspot.com will be routed to a service named `a`.
But if the service named `a` doesn't exist, then request will be routed to myall.appspot.com, which is called [soft route](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#:%7E:text=Requests%20are%20received%20by%20any%20version%20that%20is%20configured%20for%20traffic%20in%20the%20targeted%20service.%20If%20the%20service%20that%20you%20are%20targeting%20does%20not%20exist,%20the%20request%20gets%20soft%20routed).
So you can forge any url with the `myall.appspot.com` and make routing decision after you received the request in your app even if the service doesn't exist. Actually we've done this with regular expression `server_name` in `nginx`.

[soft routing explanation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#soft_routing)